# How to add vuetify in the app from starting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuetify.js

I made brand new app in vue and I want to add vuetify in the app as a framework. By running `npm install vuetify --save` this command it will add in the app but When I want to use it then there is no showing css button color while running the app.

The App.vue and the main.js files are :-

App.vue:-

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
    <v-btn color="error">Error</v-btn>
    <v-btn color="warning">Warning</v-btn>
    <v-btn color="info">Info</v-btn>
 </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

  }
</script>
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

How can I run my app with CSS button coloring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using vue-cli 3 you can just run this command; `vue add vuetify`

If you want to add it manually look at the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#existing-applications):

Here you have an example, remember to add css-loader in webpack.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 render: h => h(App)
})
```

**EDIT:**
You should not change the question like that, think about that next time it will just confuse other people looking for help or trying to help you :)

About your new question, your template is wrong. You are missing `<v-app>`

```
<v-app>
 <v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
 <v-btn color="error">Error</v-btn>
 <v-btn color="warning">Warning</v-btn>
 <v-btn color="info">Info</v-btn>
<v-app>
```

Check out the red banner in the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined):

Comment: By using this code vuetify doing work well but how to include vuetify css file in this project. @valDaHus `import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'` this is used for css but while running code it does not show any error and not showing the css colors

Comment: There are several ways to include the css-file. I'm not aware of your project-setup, maybe you can share some more information?

Comment: I edited my code for you can you now tell me why it is not showing me the button color.

Comment: I also have updated my answer now, but do not change the question it will just confuse us all. You can add more info or create a new question next time :)

Answer (score 0):

With Vue CLI 3, you can [simply](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/plugins-and-presets.html#allowing-plugin-prompts) add it as you add any other package: `vue add vuetify`.

Now if you run `git diff`, you will see that everything is done for you behind the scenes:

[image]

You can see the modified files by the end of the installation process:

[image]

In [the past](http://blog.vuejoy.com/6-add-vuetify-existing-app/), we were used to do that manually, and it was not always evident. This is a major improvement in Vue CLI 3.